# SELECT COUNT of child records as subquery within UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, union, common-table-expression

I'm trying to get a count of the number of children associated with a user. The portion of this query that selects the number of children records is: `(select count(*) from blitz_user as ua where ua.manager_id= u.id ) as "directsCount"`.

The query selects the correct number of children for all records except those with zero (0) children. For records with zero children the value of `directsCount` is still one (1).

The database in use is PostgreSQL. Please let me know if this is easier to understand with sample data. I tried to limit the length of the post in case that is not helpful.

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
    SELECT u.id,
           u.company_id as "companyId",
           u.manager_id as "managerId",
           1 as levels_down,
           (select count(*) from blitz_user as ua where ua.manager_id= u.id ) as "directsCount"
    FROM blitz_user AS u
    WHERE u.manager_id = 9

    UNION

    SELECT u.id,
           u.company_id as "companyId",
           u.manager_id as "managerId",
           levels_down + 1, 1 as levels_down
    FROM blitz_user AS u
             INNER JOIN subordinates AS s ON u.manager_id = s.id
    WHERE levels_down <= 5
)
SELECT id, "companyId", "managerId", levels_down, "directsCount"
FROM subordinates;
```

Please see the following dbfiddle for example code along with the current output.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=509411d5971efc4eddfccabf3c4d22a4

The current output is:

```
id  companyId   managerId   levels_down     directsCount
10  6           9           1               2 (correct)
11  6           9           1               1 (correct)
12  6           9           1               2 (correct)
13  6           9           1               3 (correct)
14  6           13          2               1 (should be 2)
15  6           13          2               1 (should be 2)
16  6           13          2               1 (correct)
41  6           10          2               1 (should be 3)
45  6           10          2               1 (should be 3)
49  6           11          2               1 (should be 4)
54  6           12          2               1 (should be 0)
58  6           12          2               1 (should be 3) 
17  6           14          3               1 (should be 4)
<snip>
The problem just repeats at this point for all remaining rows.
```

The "levels_down" tracks how far down the hierarchy we are. The values for "directsCount" are correct when we are only 1 levels_down, but then default to "1" for all levels_down from 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Please show sample data and its expected output, and describe how your query outputs a different result

Comment: The recursive term looks weird. Probably the section `, 1 as levels_down` should be replaced by `, (select count(*) from blitz_user as ua where ua.manager_id= u.id )`.

Comment: It would be good of you to also provide table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` scripts), your version of Postgres, the desired output, and a fiddle (ideally). Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ce0d9adcf273b0953189586d78d38848 (The example is not entirely chosen randomly, as it's from a related case.)

Comment: @TheImpaler: Yes, the problem seems to be right there, but the solution is not as simple, as the recursive term of a rCTE does not allow aggregation. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294044/3684

Comment: I have added a link to example code and updated the original post with the current vs. expected output: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=509411d5971efc4eddfccabf3c4d22a4 (edit: deleted old comment that was just a status update; fixed typo)